# Cannot create a bridge using bridge utils

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, ping, bridge

I am trying to set up a very simple 3 pc lan setup to do some network emulation using NetEm.

PC1 ---------------- Emulator Box (Running Linux 18.04)------------------- PC2

The emulator box is running linux, which has 2 Ethernet (eth0 and eth1) ports in the motherboard. I am trying to make a bridge between eth0 and eth1, so that PC1 can send or receive packets from PC2 through the box. It needs to go through box because the box would change some network parameters like add delay/loss.

The whole setup is NOT connected to internet and only connected to each other using crossover Ethernet cables.

I tried to setup the bright by editing the file in */etc/network/interfaces*
This is whats in the edited file:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0

When I restart the network using sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart,

I get the following error: Restarting networking (via systemctl):
*networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
failed!*

But i can still see the bridge when using brctl show:

bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.0xxxx2c3fe3d   no           eth0
eth1

PC1 and PC2 can ping the the Emualator box and vice versa. But PC1 and PC2 cannot ping each other. It shows request time out error.

The surprising thing is I followed the same procedure last year different machines. And it worked back then (even then it showed the error when network was restarted).

But now, it doesn't work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
NA.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? What Linux distribution is the bridge box using? Can you elaborate on your setup a little?

Comment: No its not a virtual machine. Its also a pc running linux 18.054 LTS (bionic beaver). The setup is very simple. PC1 and PC2 are connected to the box with crossover ethernet cables. So, PC1 is connected to eth0 of the box and PC2 is connected to the eth1 of the box. 
I am trying to bridge eth0 and eth1 so when i ping PC2 from PC1, it should go through the box. I have set up all the pc with static ip on same subnet mask.

Comment: Have you enabled ipv4 forwarding?

Comment: No, i did not thought of it. So do i just enable it in the linux box /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Comment: I believe so, it looks like you have everything except for that.

Comment: Nah. It still doesn't work. Not sure what's am I doing wrong here.